# SSL-enabled sites and links

Tags: http, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a page on my site which was meant to be SSL enabled.  Now, if the page has a link to an external site, does this invalidate my SSL encryption?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SSL deals with the communication between your server and the requesting browser. When using SSL the html that comprises your page is sent over an encrypted channel to the browser. The browser then decrypts the html and renders the contents. **Whether or not that html contains links to other websites than your own means absolutely nothing**.

Comment: I didn't fully investigate, that's my bad.  The src image was on an external site.  Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a section of a page from another site, for instance an iframe, then the encrypted HTML that is sent to the browser only has a link to this external content. If that external content dose not encrypt content, it dose not affect the encrypted content from your site.

How ever, this can lead to security issues. You do not control what that external content is, it could just log all of the users cookies, which could be used to steal passwords.